# disable on hover in product listing page of magento

Tags: magento

on hover buy button is showing in product listing page

i want to disable on hover and make the buy button fixed like in homepage

How to do this? i have deleted some css code but  nothing reflecting. website details i have mentioned in comment

Comment: This is my website  http://kepranprojects.com/kepran/index.php/groceries.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify this rule:

```
.category-products .products-grid li.item .actions
```

to something like this:

```
.category-products .products-grid li.item .actions {display:block;opacity:1;}
```

This will add your qty box, and button also to the page, without hover. If you want to hide them, just hide it with css.